# How do I set a PHP-FPM variable inside a nginx location block?

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

For some reason our website has one `.jsphp` file that needs to be handed to the PHP-FPM.

However, access will be denied because by default PHP-FPM only allows an extension of `.php`.

This can be solved by adding the following to `php-fpm.conf`

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .jsphp
```

But I only want to do this for a particular server location in the Nginx configuration, which is shown below

```
location ~ (\.php|\.jsphp)$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001; # 9000 for xdebug
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/usr/local/var/log/our-website.local-error.log";
}
```

Is it possible to add the PHP-FPM setting `security.limit_extensions` per server location? And if so, how do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you're asking for. The PHP-FPM config file doesn't support dynamic variables in it - everything is configured once to a set value and then the PHP-FPM pool is created with those values set.

However there are a couple of ways of solving your problem.

1. Create a new PHP-FPM pool and have it listen on a different socket.

   i.e. copy your existing pool in your php-fpm.conf file, change the socket that it's listening on to 9002 and change the value of `security.limit_extensions` for just that pool. Then in your nginx config have files that have a .jsphp extension be sent to that new pool.
2. Rename the file to be .js.php which is (imho) a better way of chaining extension types as it allows code editors to know that it is a PHP file without having to setup custom extensions in everyones editor.
   It then has a standard php extension and you don't need to worry about separate config for it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will talk to whoever created the `.jsphp` file.

Comment: 2 years later .. So this is it "php-fpm config file doesn't support dynamic variables in it". Too bad `:(` I would like to keep only one pool of workers. Is there any way to dynamically chroot php-fpm based on the vhost that has been hit by the request ? I mean setting let's say a `chrootvar` variable inside nginx server blocks holding the chroot path to set and passing it to php-fpm ?